# Run NCSDK Movidius Neural Stick on macOS

Tags: docker, neural-network, usb, ncsdk

I'm trying to run the Movidius `NCSDK` on macOS. Using the NCSDK on macOS requires VirtualBox plus docker since this USB stick must run on Ubuntu16.04 and it supports `Tensorflow` and `Caffe`.
I have successfully compiled the NCSDK on docker using [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/loretoparisi/docker/tree/master/movidius).
I have then created a `docker-machine` and attached to virtualbox as usual:

```
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox linux
$ eval $(docker-machine env linux)
$ docker-machine ls
NAME    ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER        ERRORS
linux   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v17.12.1-ce 
$ docker-machine env linux
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/loretoparisi/.docker/machine/machines/linux"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="linux"
# Run this command to configure your shell: 
# eval $(docker-machine env linux)
```

and I have plugged the device into VirtualBox, so when running the `docker` image like

```
docker run --rm -it movidius bash
```

I can see the device connected:

```
movidius@macos:~/ncsdk/examples/apps/hello_ncs_cpp$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 03e7:2150  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

where 03e7 is the Intel device as expected in the linux device ids list [here](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids):

```
03e7  Intel
    2150  Myriad VPU [Movidius Neural Compute Stick]
```

So I was supposed to make and run:

```
cd examples/apps/hello_ncs_cpp/ \
make hello_ncs_cpp \ 
make run
```

But I get

```
cd cpp; ./hello_ncs_cpp; cd ..
Error - Could not open NCS device.
    mvncStatus value: -6
```

I get the same error when trying to `python` example

```
movidius@macos:~/ncsdk/examples/apps/hello_ncs_py$ python hello_ncs.py 
Error - Could not open NCS device.
```

Looking at the python code I can see the device has been enumerated correctly:

```
     # get a list of names for all the devices plugged into the system
    ncs_names = fx.EnumerateDevices()
    if (len(ncs_names) < 1):
        print("Error - no NCS devices detected, verify an NCS device is connected.")
        quit()


    # get the first NCS device by its name.  For this program we will always open the first NCS device.
    dev = fx.Device(ncs_names[0])

    print(ncs_names[0])
```

since I can see `1` as the device name. Printing the error stacktrace for the `dev.OpenDevice()` api I have got:

```
mvncStatus.ERROR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello_ncs.py", line 43, in <module>
    dev.OpenDevice()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mvnc/mvncapi.py", line 147, in OpenDevice
    raise Exception(Status(status))
Exception: mvncStatus.ERROR
Error - Could not open NCS device.
```

I have also tried to attach the device using the `docker` option `--device` with no success trying like:

```
docker run --rm -it --net=host --privileged --device=/dev/usb/hiddev4
```

as described [here](https://gist.github.com/stonehippo/e33750f185806924f1254349ea1a4e68).

**[UPDATE]**
I'm aware of the same driver issue on the most recent version of Microsoft Windows and Microsoft Surface laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the Docker container, you must run the `make run` as root user, not a normal user.  The reason is because Docker doesn't support `udev`/`udevadm` service and so only root can access usb devices.

Comment: This fixed my issue as well - same behavior as the OP, VirtualBox vm rather than Docker, on a MacOS host.

Answer (score -1):

See if you can resolve the issue by following this thread:
https://ncsforum.movidius.com/discussion/140/mac-os-x

Please refer point 8 of Ramana.rachakonda : 
"Stick only worked when connected to a USB2 port on a USB hub that i had and not when connected to the USB3 port. If you only have USB3 ports try connecting the stick with a USB2 extension cable".